# Restart Apache Zeppelin Interpreter from Paragraph

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I want to restart spark interpreter in zeppelin from a paragraph. Currently, due to the timeout, the interpreter gets stopped automatically after 100 minutes of inactivity. However, as I want a scheduled execution of some notebooks once a day I can't use a GUI solution (restart interpreter from config manually).

I know that one solution would be to increase the timeout, but I'd rather restart it on demand than have it on all the time.